# Replace Arduino bootloader

Tags: arduino-uno, bootloader

My Arduino board is malfunctioning in its bootloading and I thought weather I can overwrite the previous bootloader on the atmega. I mean to ask than can I simply reinstall bootloader on a chip that already has a bootloader installed.

Comment: yes. you need an ISP programmer or other Arduino with "Arduino as ISP" sketch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. A Programmer that is driven from a PC and connects to SCK/MOSI/MISO/Reset/Power/Gnd (the ICSP header on an Uno/Mega), or a Standalone Programmer that can program a bootload program stored on an SD card and connects to the same ICSP pins, is needed to access the bootload memory to load/reload the bootloader.